# prop is in unrendered with shallow enzyme prop query

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have the following unit test:

```
const wrap = (props = {}) => shallow(<Col {...props} />).dive();

describe('Col', () => {
  it('should render a 100% wide div by default', () => {
    const wrapper = wrap();

    console.log(wrapper.unrendered.props);
    expect(wrapper.props().w).toBe(1);
    expect(wrapper.type().target).toBe('div');
```

The `wrapper` that is returned looks like this:

```
  ShallowWrapper {
    root: [Circular],
    unrendered:
     { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
       type:
        { [Function: StyledComponent]
          withComponent: [Function: withComponent],
          contextTypes: [Object],
          displayName: 'styled.div',
          styledComponentId: 'sc-ifAKCX',
          attrs: undefined,
          componentStyle: [Object],
          warnTooManyClasses: [Function],
          target: 'div' },
       key: null,
       ref: null,
       props: { w: 1, children: undefined },
       _owner: null,
       _store: {} },
```

So the prop I want to test for `w` is in a property named `unrendered` of the `ShallowWrapper` but not in the wrapper.

I am confused as to what this unrendered object is and why the property is not on the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The unrendered object is just implementation detail for the ShallowWrapper. You can see how it's used by inspecting the source for ShallowWrapper: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/91bf86183b08337a45c2415e89868ea46fae81c3/src/ShallowWrapper.js.

If you want to test for a particular prop `w`, then use the props() API: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html

You're already doing this in the line of code below the line that logs `unrendered`. Don't worry about the implementation details of wrapper for the purposes of testing your component (and certainly don't write tests that dig into unrendered as the implementation detail is subject to change). Instead, depend on the public API (the `props()` method in this case).